# Remove specified query in url

Tags: dart

There is a url: `https://www.google.com?id=10&name=Jack`.

Now I want to remove query `name` and the url will change to:
`https://www.google.com?id=10`.

Here is my code, you can copy and test:

```dart
void test1() {
    var urlString = 'https://www.google.com?id=10&name=Jack';
    var uri = Uri.parse(urlString);

    var queryParameters = uri.queryParameters;
    var resultUrl = uri.replace(query: queryParameters.remove('name'));
}
```

But the debug console said `Unsupported operation: Cannot modify unmodifiable map`.

It's interesting because I declare `queryParameters` with **`var`** not `final`, why it's unmodifiable?

How can I fix it?

Comment: The documentation for [`Uri.queryParameters`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/queryParameters.html) states: "The map is unmodifiable." Note that this is independent of `final`. `final` only means that you cannot reassign the variable to reference a different object, not that the object itself cannot be mutated. `queryParameters` returns a reference to an [`UnmodifiableMapView`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/UnmodifiableMapView-class.html) object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
...
var resultUrl = uri.replace(queryParameters: Map.fromEntries(queryParameters.entries.where((entry) => entry.key != 'name')));
...
```